# Eclipse + Git cannot Commit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

When I switched into my local git folder eclipse recognized automatically that it was git-related and started to put indications in my project about in what branch was I and similar. 
I did NOT have eGit installed. I can work on the project, create branches and merge them. However, there is NO commit button anywhere on Eclipse: right clicks, navigation bars etc. 
I tried to install eGit and restart but nothing changed.
This is how I see Eclipse in Git Perspective.
[image: Eclipse workspace]

Can anyone explain me what's happening?

Comment: you have to import a project from the git repository first, then switch back to java perspective; you will find commit menu under project context menu (right click) -> team -> commit

Answer (score 2):

Click `Windows > Customize Perspective` Select all Git actions. Refer pic below. All actions will appear in Toolbar. Check **Command Groups and Availability** tab and select Git command groups here.

[image]